# why jwt.sign() method only works on string secret key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, secret-key, jwt

I am trying to learn `JWT` authentication token, but I am having an issue.

In my code, this line works fine.

```
const token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'ea7aae59cedb7346c');
```

But this line doesn't work.

```
const token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, ea7aae59cedb7346c);
```

To me it seems like when I try to put the jet authentication secret key **inline** without making it a **string value**, it doesn't work.

Why is this happening? What's the difference between `stringified key value` and `regular key value` in `jwt.sign()` method?

Comment: This question requires more details, like which language are you working with (it seems javascript, in that case require which environment are you working with i.e nodejs ). It also require which JWT package/dependency you are using ? So far normally JWT is not supported natively or language sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, [options, callback])
```

[Source](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback)

const token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');

> payload could be an object literal, buffer or string representing
>   valid JSON.

So in your case  you pass "payload" as a Object  and "secret" is "shhhhh"

as per the docuemtation

> secretOrPrivateKey is a string, buffer, or object containing either
>   the secret for HMAC algorithms or the PEM encoded private key for RSA
>   and ECDSA.

So you are not provide a valid arugument which is long value not string

you can pass value as a string or pass algorithm in secretOrPrivateKey
like this

```
hmacSha256(key, message) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking this question.
"secretOrPrivateKey is a string, buffer, or object containing either the secret for HMAC algorithms or the PEM encoded private key for RSA and ECDSA." 
as stated in https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

I have placed my in .env file and it is working okay. 
like this. [image]

and the .env file key is this.[image]